# Make chat transcripts/conversations downloadable as .pdf

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Recently, in the ServerFault chat room there's been some interesting, technical conversation (yes, it does happen). While I can "bookmark" a conversation for later reading, you still need to be online, so could it be made available/exportable as a .pdf (much like Wikipedia does with it's [Wikipedia:Books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Books) project). While I'm just using The Comms Room as an example maybe other sites and rooms would use it too.

Granted, it would have to add the necessary legality terms to the bottom but I think it would be very useful to refer to without having to dig through the transcript, list of stars and list of conversations.

Comment: Are such chats not "polluted" by other, unrelated chat messages? If they are, then [The Printliminator free bookmarklet](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/), combined with printing to PDF in the browser, might be better?

Comment: Why would you want a pdf when you can just save the html?

Comment: This looks like feature creep to me. Why would anyone need PDFs?

Comment: Personally, as much as I hate .pdf's, it's an "all in one" format, as if you save the html page you get a subfolder with a bungle of images and whatnot. I'd prefer them all in a single document (but hey, that's me and my high OCD levels kicking in).

Comment: Can't you just print the whole chat page to PDF directly?

Comment: @AdamRackis, actually, that's not a bad idea. I'll give that a go and see how the results come out.

Comment: @AdamRackis, would you mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: @tombull89 - done, per your request :)

Comment: Saving as HTML is clunky; either you have to read the source (which is, shall we say, messy in this case), or you have to be online for the JavaScript to work.  I found this question by starting to ask for a similar feature (text dump without JS).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the chat rooms already have a good print view, so if you want the chat logs in PDF, I would recommend installing a PDF printer and just printing to that.

That should get you what you want without the team having to spend time implementing a new feature.

Comment: That works for one page, but what if you want to save a multi-day transcript (too big to bookmark) in one PDF rather than one page per day?