# Is there a quick way to export a chat?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat

I've been participating in a Stack Exchange chat that has some great information, including some incremental code development showing the actual code as we work on it.

I went to try to save the chat as a text file but could find no functionality to do so. The closest I could find was the "Full transcript" button, but despite its name, it doesn't appear to actually show the full transcript; it only shows the activity of one date at a time.

How can one export an entire chat that spans more than just a couple of days?

I did find a [10-year-old request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116853/make-chat-transcripts-conversations-downloadable-as-pdf).

But the comment from "valued moderator" Monica is spot-on: the accepted answer is not effective for chats spanning more than a couple days.  Also, I simply may not be seeing it, but I don't see a "Print view", as recommended in the accepted answer, anywhere.

Also, unlike that question, I would prefer the output to be a simple text file.

If this functionality is not available, could it be added?  Right now, I have to make sure I visit the chat and post something regularly just to keep it from being auto-deleted.

Comment: Its an ugly solution but I wonder if using 'reader' mode on your browser of choice might be a modern equivlent of print mode. I know FF has it, as does my vivaldi

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks for the idea.  Checking it out in Firefox now...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ah, your excellent idea was so close!  Long code blocks get truncated with a "*(show full text)*" link.  When you click on those links (for which you can manually search), the code doesn't expand; instead you get redirected to another page that *only* shows that code.  So close though!  Thank you again for your clever idea.

Comment: Chats get auto-frozen, but not auto-deleted.  Only a mod can delete a chat room.  Otherwise you can still access the messages afterwards...

Comment: @Anonymous That's what I thought too, but I recently entered a (different) and I thought it said it was going to be deleted due to inactivity.  That wasn't a chat I want to save, so I didn't pay it much mind.  I'll see if I perhaps misread the message that popped up.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358814/223820

Answer (score 6):

I've made a Python script to do just that based on [this GitHub project](https://gist.github.com/nicktimko/2b7e21c196d9e74c69fbd7f5b79014cb):

```py
import time
import requests

MAX_MSG_COUNT = 500

def get_messages(room_id, domain, before=None, n=MAX_MSG_COUNT, session=None):
    # SE Chat API endpoint
    url = 'http://chat.{}/chats/{}/events'.format(domain, room_id)
    params = {
        'mode': 'Messages',
        'msgCount': n,
    }
    if before is not None:
        params['before'] = before
    if session is None:
        session = requests.session()
        
    global r
    r = messages = session.post(url, params)
    messages = session.post(url, params).json()['events']
    earliest = min(msg['message_id'] for msg in messages)
    done = len(messages) != n
    
    return messages, earliest, done


def get_all_messages(room_id, domain_name, throttle=1):
    """
    Get all messages from the provided room ID. Throttle controls the inter-
    request delay to avoid being too obnoxious.
    """
    messages = []

    s = requests.session()

    new_messages, earliest, done = get_messages(room_id, domain_name, session=s)
    messages.extend(new_messages)
    while not done:
        time.sleep(throttle)
        new_messages, earliest, done = get_messages(room_id, domain_name, before=earliest, session=s)
        messages.extend(new_messages)
        
    return messages

def write_to_file(room_id, domain, file_name = 'messages.json'):
    messages = get_all_messages(room_id, domain, 0)
    import json
    with open(file_name, 'w') as archive:
        archive.write(json.dumps(list(sorted(messages, key = lambda message: message['time_stamp'])))) # or archive.write(json.dumps(list(sorted(messages, key = lambda message: message['time_stamp'])), indent=4)) to pretty-print

def main():
    room_id = input('Enter room ID: ')
    domain_name = input('Enter domain name: ')
    write_to_file(room_id, domain_name, input('Enter file name (or press enter for messages.json): ') or 'messages.json')
    print('Done!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Interesting... thank you!  I'll take a look at it soon (which in my world right now means anywhere between 1 hour and 9-10 months!).  Which version of Python does your code require?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket It's designed for Python 3.8, but it probably runs on any version of Python 3.

Comment: Thank you... I'll definitely check it out as time and energy permits.  I think it would be appropriate for SE to have this functionality integrated without having to run a Python script (I would guess a good chunk of SE users have no idea how to do that, or would never spend the time to do so), but nonetheless I really appreciate the script and will definitely check it out.  Thanks again.